# How to center an ImageView and then offset it to the left or right?

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview

I have two Image Views that are two football helmets facing each other.  I'm wanting to center them and then offset them left/right a little to provide a little space between them.  Here is one of the image view's xml at the moment.

```
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/hometeam"
   android:scaleType="centerInside"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="70px"
   android:layout_y="90px"
   android:layout_marginLeft="25px">
```

I was trying to offset it using [android:layout_marginLeft="25px"] however I'm guessing that's not working for me because of the [android:scaleType="centerInside"]. Anyone know a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Try gravity on their holder view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `android:gravity="center"` for the Layout.

Comment: Thanks Pentium10, Praveen, that worked replacing the [android:scaleType="CenterInside"] with [android:gravity="center"] and then instead of [android:layout_marginLeft="25px"] using [android:layout_paddingLeft="25px"] ! :D Thanks again